Visual Studio 2022 Community version
In Visual Studio 2022 Community in a Forms (Framework (4.8)) application I cannot get to the visual representation of the Designer in order to use Toolbox. The application works properly but in Visual Studio 2022 Community environment I cannot get to the form to amend it by using Toolbox. Please advise.
I have tried Rebuild, re-starting Visual Studio, Repair Visual Studio 2022 Community, re-loading Windows 10 etc.

IMO, reformulating the title of your question would greatly help it to attract people familiar with the problem.

What exactly do you mean by "I cannot get to the visual representation of the Designer in order to use Toolbox."? What exactly happens if you double click the form.cs filename in the Solution Explorer window?

In that right click option I do not get the View Designer option, various others are there.

When I left double click on Form.cs nothing happens.

I mean Form1.cs.

I tried using Framework 4.72 rather than 4.8. It worked. Maybe that was just chance and something else happened.
